# When creating a thread how do I run the threads main method?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

The main method of my thread is:

```
void thrMain(const std::vector<long>& list, std::vector<int>& result,
    const int startInd, const int endInd) {
   for (int i = startInd; (i < endInd); i++) {
       result[i] = countFactors(list[i]);
   }
}
```

I create a list of threads each time using another method:

```
std::vector<int> getFactorCount(const std::vector<long>& numList, const int thrCount) {
   // First allocate the return vector
   const int listSize = numList.size();
   const int count = (listSize / thrCount) + 1;
   std::vector<std::thread> thrList;  // List of threads
   const std::vector<long> interFac(thrCount);  // Intermediate factors
   // Store factorial counts
   std::vector<int> factCounts(numList.size());
   for (int start = 0, thr = 0; (thr < thrCount); thr++, start += count) {
       int end = std::max(listSize, (start + count));
       thrList.push_back(std::thread(thrMain, std::ref(numList), 
            std::ref(interFac[thr]), start, end));
   }
   for (auto& t : thrList) {
       t.join();
   }
   // Return the result back
   return factCounts;
}
```

The main problem I am having is that the `std::ref(interFac[thr])` is making my `#include <thread>` file not work. I have tried taking away the pass by reference and that does not help the problem.

Comment: Usually, a thread is represented by a function.  This is the thread's "main" function.  The operating system will run this function when scheduling the thread.

Comment: Remember, adding more threads may not make your program more efficient.  Worst case, your threads get scheduled on a single core or processor (much like other programs would).  All threads require overheads for 1) creation; 2) maintenance; and 3) deletion (joining).  More threads require more overhead.

Comment: For peace of mind, I highly recommend a separate and distinct function for each thread.  Code sharing and reintrancy adds complexit that you don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `interFac` is for, but it looks like this:

```
thrList.push_back(std::thread(thrMain, std::ref(numList), 
     std::ref(interFac[thr]), start, end));
```

should be this:

```
thrList.push_back(std::thread(thrMain, std::ref(numList), 
     std::ref(factCounts), start, end));
```

Then [it compiles](https://ideone.com/0CwbnY).